# Not getting proper output in opencart product page

Tags: php, css, opencart

Hi I am trying to get video when it is set at the place of base image but when i am trying to do that I am also getting base image near to video. I had also try with an `if...else` statement to try and retrieve expected output but was not possible...

**code what i am using**

```
<?php 
    if ($product_videos) { 
        foreach ($product_videos as $product_video) {
            if($product_video['base_image'] == 1) { 
 ?>
<div class="image">
    <iframe class="youtube-player" height="228px" width="228px" type="text/html" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $product_video['youtube_id']; ?><?php echo $youtube_extension; ?>"></iframe>
</div>
<?php
            }
        }
    } else if($thumb) {
?>
<div class="image">
    <a href="<?php echo $popup; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" class="colorbox"><img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" id="img_<?php echo $product_id; ?>" /></a>
</div>
<?php 
    } 
?>
```

**Wrong Output what I am getting**

[image]

I don't want image near to video.

Comment: What is your desired layout/output?

Comment: my desired layout is I don't want Image (monitor)(right to video) when there is video is there....

Answer (score 0):

Try Bellow code..I'm sure it will work

```
     <?php if ($product_videos) { ?>
    <?php foreach ($product_videos as $product_video) { ?>
        <?php if($product_video['base_image'] == 1) { ?>
            <div class="image">
           <iframe class="youtube-player" height="228px" width="228px" type="text/html" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $product_video['youtube_id']; ?><?php echo $youtube_extension; ?>"></iframe>
            </div>
       <?php } ?>
   <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($product_video['base_image'] == 0 ) { ?>
    <?php if($thumb) { ?>
  <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $popup; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" class="colorbox"><img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" id="img_<?php echo $product_id; ?>" /></a></div>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nikunj Patel.... your solution is working properly... :)